# facebook live stream: see more post in public than in logging

Tags: facebook, friend, public, posts

I included a facebook live stream into a website - no problems so far. While I stay logged out I can see all public post from customers facebook site. But when I logged in with my facebook account I only can see three old posts, posted from customers mobile phone. (No newer posts from mobile.) This is only because I'm in a friendship with this custom via facebook. All other friends of this customer see the three posts as well.
If I log in with another accout who is not a friend of this customer, then there are all posts (the same as stay logged out of facebook).

Could anyone please explain me why this is happen and what can I or the customer do to show all posts by the friends?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug in their live stream plugin. You should log a bug with Facebook. Please post the link to the bug report here.  Thanks.